# AutoHotKey SendText not working in Google Sheets

Tags: autohotkey

I've got an AutoHotKey macro setup to type text thusly:

```
^+!v::SendText A_Clipboard
```

Ctrl-Alt-Shift-V types the clipboard wherever I am.
This works great, except if I'm in a Google Sheet in Firefox.
If I've got an empty cell selected in Sheets, then instead of activating the cell and typing in the text, it just activates the cell.
At that point, if I hit the combo again, the text is typed in as it should be.
Note also that it works fine in Google Docs, though that's probably because there's no equivalent of having a cell selected, but not activated.

I've poked around with some different key combinations, it doesn't seem to matter what keys I used to trigger it - I tried various combos modifiers and the windows key, no change. I also tried F11 (no modifiers) an still does the same thing.

It seems like Firefox is getting hold of the keys in some way that's interfering with AHK - any good ideas as to how to work around this?

AHK version 2.0.11, Firefox version 123.0.1 (64-bit).

Comment: On my system (Windows 11, Firefox 123.0.1 64-bit, AHK 2.0.11) all combinations work, except those with Alt.

Comment: @Relax - well isn't that interesting. I just tried it on a system I have at work, and it's working just fine. There must be something else on my home box interfering with the setup.